# Css hover div to show another div

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm having some trouble about css hover effect.
I have external container within 2 div.In left div i need hover effect that show right div(previously hidden).

I'll report code

```
<div class="block-attr">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right">Hidden text  </div>
</div>
```

but this instruction (right div it's hidden with display:none;) seem not to work.

```
.block-attr .left:hover .right{display:block;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the adjacent selector `+` to do that. Check below example

Read more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information_Selectors_based_on_relationships

```css
.right {
  display: none;
}
.block-attr .left:hover + .right {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-attr">
  <div class="left">Hover here</div>
  <div class="right">Hidden text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.left:hover + .right{ display: block;}
```